# Filter Dataframe based on condition coming in request

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe that I need to filter based on condition receiving in request from UI.
**request example:**

```
{
"table": "abc",
"condition": "A=98 and C=73 and D='rendom_char'"
}
```

**dataframe sample:**

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 85 | 39 | 54 | td |
| 1 | 39 | 51 | 23 | abc |
| 2 | 98 | 17 | 73 | def |
| 3 | 98 | 52 | 73 | def |
| 4 | 85 | 52 | 21 | rst |
| 5 | 61 | 89 | 31 | xvz |

so suppose if I get condition from UI that `"condition": "A=98 and C=73 and D='def'"` or `"condition": "A=98 and C=73"`
output should be like :

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 98 | 17 | 73 | def |
| 3 | 98 | 52 | 73 | def |

The issue I'm facing is how to convert that string condition getting from UI into python form so that I can apply filter on datafram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with replace `=` to double `=`:

```
d = {"condition": "A=98 and C=73 and D='def'"}
print (df.query(d['condition'].replace('=','==')))
    A   B   C    D
2  98  17  73  def
3  98  52  73  def

d = {"condition": "A=85 and C=21"}
print (df.query(d['condition'].replace('=','==')))

    A   B   C    D
4  85  52  21  rst
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can query pandas dataframe in SQL fashion with [pandasql](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/):

```
import pandasql as psql
...

req = {"table": "abc", "condition": "A=98 and C=73 and D='def'"}
q = f"select * from df where {req['condition']}"

print(psql.sqldf(q, locals()))
```

---

```
    A   B   C    D
0  98  17  73  def
1  98  52  73  def
```